# Database which has categorized the english words into matching emotion

Tags: database, api, nlp

is there a database or api which has the categorized version of English words into the matching emotion?

e.g: - http://www.psychpage.com/learning/library/assess/feelings.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One useful resource is the [NRC Word-Emotion Association Lexicon](http://www.saifmohammad.com/WebPages/lexicons.html) compiled by Saif Mohammad. It lists the sentiments (positive, negative) and emotions (anger, anticipation, disgust, fear, joy, sadness, surprise, trust) for around 14,000 English words.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look into the topic of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis If you are good with doing it in Python take a look at this demo: http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/ Which is able to get if a sentence is positive or negative using NLTK.

Comment: i have done the sentiment analysis using alchemy api.Im looking for a database which categorized the words into matching emotion. like this : -
http://www.psychpage.com/learning/library/assess/feelings.html